# Azure Zero-downtime Deployments - separate FE/BE App Services

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-app-service-plans

I have an application that consists of an Angular 2+ frontend deployed on a separate App Service to my .NET Core backend (per environment).

I'm investigating zero-downtime deployments with Azure App Service staging slots, however I don't understand how I'd have this setup in my case, because:

My FE and BE are deployed via DevOps CI/CD automation, and are built + deployed in an Azure Pipeline - meaning my Angular app has its API URL set in whichever environment.ts file is chosen (depending on which environment is being deployed to).

What is the correct way to achieve having a zero-downtime deployment setup in Azure in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that you won't be able to use deployment slots with your Angular app, since the configuration is bundled with the code. You can use Azure Static Web App with CDN to achieve this.

For your backend, deployment slots with auto swap enabled should get you what you're looking for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/static-website-content-delivery-network

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots